# Users tab does not appear to be working.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

On the main site when I click on "users" to see the rankings, I have options to sort by various time duration options. It appears that:

"week" gives "day"

"month" gives "month"

"quarter" also gives "month"

"year" gives "year"

"all" gives "all"

Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: The best time to test this is on a Monday which is January 1st.

Comment: I have changed *users* in the title to *user tab*. The original title *Users does not appear to be working* seemed to indicate that users of this site are lazy. (And jokes aside, I think in this way the title is a wee clearer.) I am not sure what a good choice of tags for this question could be.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Weeks start on Sunday.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm used to the fact that outside of Israel, weekdays start with Mondays.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Weekdays as in "working days"? That probably, but nevertheless, on Stack Exchange, and also in many other countries (e.g. the USA, iirc), the week starts on Sunday. (And I never accepted the change when it was made here, **my** weeks still start on Sunday.)

Comment: @Daniel: Hm. So you start your week with a day off? Sounds lazy! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm a Haskeller, lazy is my second nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "week" is actually "week to date". Since today is the first day of the week, week to date and day are the same. Similarly, this is the first month of the quarter.

Comment: Ah, thank you for enlightening me. Should I delete the post or leave it?

Comment: @NotNotLogical Leave it. Other users may have the same question.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit to Alex Becker's answer, if you hover your cursor over the time-frame name, you'll be told what the span of that time-frame is (where days begin at [00:00:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27199/214632)):

---

- **Top users this week**

  [image: Top users this week]

---

- **Top users this month**

  [image: top users this month]

---

- **Top users this quarter**

  [image: top users this quarter]

---

- **Top users this year**

  [image: top users this year]

---

- **Top users all**

  [image: top users since math.SE's origin]